# How do I define an event then kick off a delegate when the event happens

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I know this is really basic stuff but I'm struggling to wrap my mind around it.

Ok so I have a method that I want to run:

```
public static void DelegateTest(string testStuff)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(testStuff);
    }
}
```

Then, outside of the scope of this method (but within the scope of my class) I define my delegate with the same output type and input parameters as my method:

```
public delegate void myDelegate(string test);
```

I instantiate my delegate like so:

```
myDelegate md = new myDelegate(DelegateTest);
```

I can then kick off my method as many times as I like by BeginInvoking the delegate, and the methods will run side by side in separate threads.

```
md.BeginInvoke("Hello World", null, null);
md.BeginInvoke("Hello World Again", null, null);
md.BeginInvoke("Hello World A Third Time", null, null);
```

How do I now define an event and only kick off my method asynchronously when the event happens? Also, what are the limitations on what an event can be? Can more or less anything that happens on my computer be defined as an event or only certain things?

Edit: Say for example, after doing the above, I want to create an event and define this event as 'the space bar has been pressed'. Every time the space bar is pressed, this is the event happening. When the event happens, I want to start my method asynchronously, I don't want to start my method asynchronously if the space bar hasn't been pressed.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Do you really mean "asynchronously"? Or do you mean "synchronously"? It seems they are already asynchronous.

Comment: I know that, the question is, once I have created a method, then a delegate and I know how to start the method asynchronously, how do I then create an event and associate the event with the delegate. Do I need to update my question to make this clear?

Comment: @JMK you create the event by invoking it as you've already figured out.  How and When then is done is up to you.  Sounds like you are trying to catch an event outside your program?  What event are you trying to capture?

Comment: @JMK ahh, your latest edit makes more sense.  For keypress events it depends whether you are creating a winform/wpf/web application really.  However, you won't need your own delegate in any case - they are already there, you just hook a handler up to the right event - see here for a winforms example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress.aspx

Comment: Thanks Simon, however if the delegate isn't already there how would I go about creating and defining my own event?

Comment: @JMK I've linked in my answer to a good example page on code project of how to create your own events.

Comment: @JMK exactly as you've specified above.  However, it won't just be fired on an arbitrary action - someone, somewhere, has to call 'Invoke' when the action happens.  If that isn't provided by the framework you are using then you'll have to figure out a way to do that yourself, which might involve Windows messages or something else depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Invoke rather than BeginInvoke for synchronous calls.

EDIT: as per ThePower's answer, you don't need the Invoke, you can just call your delegate as if it were a function (because it is!).

EDIT2: You are actually trying to register an event handler.  For this you don't need to create your own delegate.  An example for handling the KeyPress event in WinForms:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        KeyPress += OnKeyPressHandler;
    }


    private void OnKeyPressHandler(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs keyPressEventArgs)
    {
     //TODO: whatever you need to do...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however the question is more about events. I have created a method, then a delegate to match the method, then I am starting it asynchronously (which I want to). Now that I have got this far, how do I then create an event and link it to my delegate?

Comment: @JMK I think you may be misunderstanding what events are?  Could you specify exactly what you want to do?

Comment: @JMK You'll want to look at Event then, rather than delegate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it as an `event`, check out the event type. There's a good example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9355/Creating-advanced-C-custom-events).

Although, if you want to use your delegate...

You have already defined Asynchronous, so for Synchronous use :

```
md("Hello World", null, null);
md("Hello World Again", null, null);
md("Hello World A Third Time", null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. In C#, for all practical purposes, an event is a delegate, meaning that any delegate can be used as an event.

Using your example:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(string test);
```

You can now use `MyDelegate` as an event in a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public event MyDelegate MyEvent;
}
```

You can now register event handlers with `MyEvent` and then in the event handler you can execute any code you want. From a traditional sense, this is the only way to define events in C#.

Another option to consider is using a publish/subscribe pattern such as an `EventAggregator`. This pattern doesn't typically rely on delegates and instead relies on an aggregator object to notify all subscribers of a published event. In this scenario, the event can really be any object that contains the information expected by the subscribers.